# how to get width and height of TiledMap in the latest Version of Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, tilemap

I am making a tiled based game, I want not to let the camera show places, where there is no map... this is a obvious solution I got from a tutorial

```
if(camera.position.x<400){
    camera.position.x=400;
}else if(camera.position.x>map.width*map.tileWidth-400){
    camera.position.x=map.width*map.tileWidth-400;
}

if(camera.position.y<240){
    camera.position.y=240;
}else if(camera.position.y>map.height*map.tileHeight-240){
    camera.position.y=map.height*map.tileHeight-240;
}

camera.update();
```

but I don't know how to get width & height of the tiledMap in the latest version of libgdx

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TiledMap.java

Seems strange... I even tried the Super classes but couldn't find. Please help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
TiledMap tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("path/to/tiled/map.tmx");   
MapProperties prop = tiledMap.getProperties();

int mapWidth = prop.get("width", Integer.class);
int mapHeight = prop.get("height", Integer.class);
int tilePixelWidth = prop.get("tilewidth", Integer.class);
int tilePixelHeight = prop.get("tileheight", Integer.class);

int mapPixelWidth = mapWidth * tilePixelWidth;
int mapPixelHeight = mapHeight * tilePixelHeight;
```

The `mapWidth` and `mapHeight` are the dimensions of the map in tiles. So they would both be 10 in a 10x10 grid. The `tilePixelWidth` and `tilePixelHeight` are the dimensions of the tiles in pixels. In a 32x32 tileset they would both be 32. Multiplying the dimensions together you will get the map dimensions in pixels.

Comment: Hi there, mobo! Could you explain a little bit more about the snippet? It might help others.

Comment: MapProperties is just an Object map that holds any properties of the TileMap. If you are using a .tmx file its any of the properties in the first line: width, height, tilewidth, tileheight, orientation are all there by default. The cod was wrong and I am fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot - your contribution is appreciated I'm sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

The information you seek is in the object of TiledMapLayer.

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get(0);
```

or

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get("my_layer");
```

then you can use:

- `layer.getTileWidth();` to access tile width in pixels.
- `layer.getTileHeight();` to access tile height in pixels.
- `layer.getWidth();` to access number of tiles, horizontally.
- `layer.getHeight();` to access number of tiles, vertically.
- `layer.getTileWidth() * layer.getWidth();` to work out the map width in pixels.
- `layer.getTileHeight() * layer.getHeight();` to work out the map height in pixels.

To set change a specific tile,

```
TiledMapTile tile = null;
int column = 0;
int row = 0;
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setTile(tile);
layer.setCell(column, row, cell);
```

and to get a specific tile,

```
int column = 0;
int row = 0;
Cell cell = layer.getCell(column, row);
TiledMapTile tile = cell.getTile();
```